# Magento: change advanced search layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, templates, magento

I want to change the advanced search layout to my needs.

Instead of select boxes I want to have radio buttons with a picture and text in the description. For one button the layout is:

```
[button][image][text]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the magento admin, and under system->configuration->Developer enable 'Template Path Hints' and 'Block Path hints'.

Then you should be able to know which template is used for rendering the select boxes, open that template and replace them with radio buttons.

Good luck!

Comment: This answer is useful, but because the view has a loop (to create the elements) it's difficult to replace the components.

Answer (score 3):

All the templates you'll need are in /app/design/frontend/default/default/catalogsearch/